# How do I interface with a type library in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, interface, com, typelib

I have a type library in Delphi, successfully imported using RAD Studio's associated wizard, which I am struggling to interface with.

I have attempted to make use of Delphi's *ComObj* unit but am greeted with an error message at runtime which says *Class not registered* when calling the *CreateComObject* method.

```
qmini := ComObj.CreateComObject(CLASS_SpectrometerWrapper) as ISpectrometer;
```

The type library itself is listed in RAD Studio's registered type libraries.

The unit contains the following TGUIDs:

```
const
  // TypeLibrary Major and minor versions
  RgbDriverKitWrapperMajorVersion = 1;
  RgbDriverKitWrapperMinorVersion = 0;

  LIBID_RgbDriverKitWrapper: TGUID = '{44E660F8-97CB-3FF8-8CC3-2300CE977BE1}';

  IID_ISpectrometer: TGUID = '{92810FFB-7F93-4C03-B7FF-13835799DB87}';
  IID__SpectrometerWrapper: TGUID = '{B62678F5-0EF2-3147-9C46-F86910D0D18F}';
  CLASS_SpectrometerWrapper: TGUID = '{8F55541E-E58D-49B4-BB7D-C3699C8BDEEE}';
```

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Comment: They (RGB Photonics) have that wrapper in the `\Sample code\COM Wrapper\RgbDriverKitWrapper\RgbDriverKitWrapper.csproj` project. That one needs to be built and registered (which is done by the `\Sample code\COM Wrapper\RegisterWrapperAndExportTLB\RegisterWrapperAndExportTLB.vcxproj` project). Did you go through this step?

Comment: Yes, I went through that step to obtain the type library which I subsequently imported to RAD Studio.

Comment: So, regasm succeeded assembly registration (not generating type library)? Asking because it sounds it didn't. Try to run `regasm RgbDriverKitWrapper.dll` from command line (elevated, I think).

Comment: Error means that the COM server has not been registered

Comment: How is a COM server registered? Can this be done through RAD Studio?

Comment: Use TRegSvr that comes with Delphi or Windows' RegSvr32.

Comment: FYI, `\Sample code\COM Wrapper\Readme.txt` states as the first step to compile and run the sample project, _"You need to have administrator priviledges"_. That's because of the COM server registration (that `RegisterWrapperAndExportTLB.vcxproj` project). You can just run elevated VS command line and run there `regasm RgbDriverKitWrapper.dll`.

Comment: I have placed the .exe I created in the same folder as the example executable and now the software works. How can I work around this?